# Client server connections

Tags: database, socket.io

I am about to write an app that should take connections from about 30 to 60 IOT computers who each send small packets of data (each sends their data within 3 seconds intervals, continuously but they all do it at slightly random moments). The clients will only be pushing data that I need to collect. They won't request data from a central desktop.

I'm wondering what would be a better design for this monitoring desktop application (not a web app).

Let the IOT 60 computers report their data to a sockets construction, then in the app serialize it (although network data is already serialized), and put it in a database (SQLite or MySQL).

Let all the 30 to 60 clients themselves connect directly to the database, and find a way to create a live view of the data.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably debatable, but I would recommend the

***first option, using an intermediate server***,

for several reasons:

1. You could use UDP (stateless fire-and-forget) to collect the data from the clients, for better performance and scalability. Regardless of whether you let the clients re-connect to the database every 3 seconds or keep the connections open, it wouldn't be efficient.
2. The intermediate server would basically be a middleware. Meaning, if the data format (client-side) or database structure is changed you only need to update the intermediate server, instead of all the clients.
3. You could scale up and add redundancy (with caching) by adding more intermediate servers if needed. If you did that with the database, you'd have to keep them in sync somehow.
4. In terms of security, it's always better to put the database behind an application server (3-tier architecture) and configure the firewall so only the application server can connect to it.

Comment: No reason to use UDP and not know the reliability.  An IOT can just fire an http post to send data.  Quick and well supported and plenty scalable.  60 devices is nothing unless they're sending data continually, in which case you'd use a continuous connection like plain TCP with your own protocol or webSocket.

Comment: Agreed, a RESTful interface using TCP would be much more compatible and do just fine in terms of performance - if the number of clients doesn't explode one day.

Comment: well i start with 15 clients but 60 will be at max

Comment: Oh i forgot to tell, but those clients will only push information (they dont need to ask something).

Comment: @jfriend00 the data send is continuously 24h a day